# Should I use Plpgsql to loop through table instead of using SQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a job which runs every night to load changes into a temporary table and apply those changes to the main table.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXIST tmp AS SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 0;

COPY tmp FROM PROGRAM '';

11 SQL queries to update 'mytable' based on data from 'tmp'
```

I have a large number of queries to delete duplicates from tmp, update values in tmp, update values in the main table and insert new rows into the main table. Is it possible to loop over both tables using plpgsql instead?

```sql
UPDATE mytable m
    SET "Field" = t."Field" +1
FROM tmp t
WHERE (t."ID" = m."ID");
```

In this example, it is simple change of a column value. Instead, I want to do more complex operations on both the main table as well as the temp table.

EDIT: so here is some is some PSEUDO code of what I imagine.

```
LOOP tmp t, mytable m
BEGIN
-- operation in plpgsql including UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
END
WHERE t.ID = m.ID;
```

Comment: Yes, just put the queries you are running now in the function in the proper order.

Comment: try first to create a [sql user-defined function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc.html) or a [sql user-defined procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html) before switching to the plpgsql language

Comment: I already put the queries in a procedure and it does work, but it seems to inefficient to me because I have to do so many queries to execute and as I need to do more complex operations I would need to add more queries. So what I was thinking about is whether I can  have a nested LOOP.

Comment: You can certainly get what you are looking in psql and looping. But you state "*but it seems to inefficient to me ...*", you may want to keep in mind the looping with where SQL is involved is generally the **most inefficient** method there is.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Programming background and no experience with SQL tends to make you define solutions in terms of a program. I was able to reduce the number of queries to make to more palatable. How bad is to use a function to calculate a value in an UPDATE query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plpgsql FOR to [loop over query results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).

```
DECLARE
    myrow RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR myrow IN SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (id)
    LOOP
       ... do something with the row ...
    END LOOP;
END
```

If you want to update a table while looping over it, you can create a [FOR UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-cursors.html) cursor, but that won't work if the query is a join, because then you're not opening an update cursor on a table.

Note writing to/updating temp tables is much faster than writing to normal tables because temp tables don't have WAL and crash recovery overhead, and they're owned by one single connection, so you don't have to worry about locks.

If you put a query inside the loop, it will be executed many times though, which could get pretty slow. It's usually faster to use bulk queries, even if they're complicated.

If you want to UPDATE many rows in the temp table with values that depend on other tables and joins, it could be faster to run several updates on the temp table with different join and WHERE conditions.